# PHP mkdir 0777 fail chmod 0777 works

Tags: php, chmod, mkdir

using PHP 5.2.14, this is what happens

```
[user@VE213 public_html]$ php -r "mkdir('directory', 0777);"
[user@VE213 public_html]$ ls -lt
drwxrwxr-x  2 rankranger rankranger 4096 Dec  8 17:28 directory

[user@VE213 public_html]$ php -r "chmod('directory', 0777);"
[user@VE213 public_html]$ ls -lt
drwxrwxrwx  2 rankranger rankranger 4096 Dec  8 17:28 directory
```

Did not find any related bugs in the php bug list, any idea?

Comment: What's your umask? (Does mkdir use umask?)

Answer (score 19):

```
$old = umask(0);
mkdir($dir,0777);
umask($old);
```

Read this, 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Additional, Check the top directory that you make new directory.

Example)

> pwd
>   /data/log

```
$dir="/data/log/query";
$old = umask(0); 
mkdir($dir,0777); 
umask($old);
```

> /data/log must 0777.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a bug. See http://php.net/umask - you probably have an umask of 0002. The permission of what you create is `yourmode & ~umask`, so it takes the write-bit for everyone away from 0777.

Answer (score 5):

Working as documented. mkdir respects umask, chmod doesn't.

Comment: It might work at it is supposed to, but the whole principle of umask is usually not what you would expect.