# PHP mkdir: 0777 becomes 0755?

Tags: php, linux, security, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP mkdir 0777 fail chmod 0777 works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390422/php-mkdir-0777-fail-chmod-0777-works)

My PHP code has something like this:

> $success = mkdir($directory_name,
>   0777, TRUE);

When I look at the actual folder it created, the permissions are 0755. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual permissions are impacted by the current [`umask()`](http://php.net/umask) value. If it is limited to `755`, so will the directory permissions. (It's `xor`ed off the requested `777`)

Comment: if you really want to create a world-writeable directory, you'll want a umask of 0

Answer (score 2):

Your umask is probably set to 0022 (a common default), preventing the write bits from being set for group and other. You can use the [umask function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) to change the current umask.

But then, why are you creating a directory that's world-writable? Not a good idea.